# Android build with multiple productFlavors buildTypes using travis

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, continuous-integration, travis-ci

My Android project has multiple build type and productFlavors

```
   flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        favor1 {
            applicationId "com.abc.android"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1"
        }
        flavor2 {
            applicationId "com.abc.android"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "2"
       }
    }



    buildTypes {

        staging {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        develop {
            applicationIdSuffix ".develop"
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
```

I have placed my file, say(Abc.java) under each of flavor1staging, flavor1develop, flavor2staging, flavor2develop directory

I can do ./gradlew assemblefalor1staging on my local Android studio and it works fine but when run using travis it cannot map the file and gives me error Unresolved reference Abd

Similarly for any string resources that are defined in the flavorbuild folders but not in the main folder

Answer (score 0):

I have a question does the build is working fine if you give it only 1 build type?

Because according to Travis-CI they do not mention about supporting multiple build types in this link

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/

As all builds in the example containing only one build as you can see in these examples

https://github.com/andrewhr/rxjava-android-example/blob/master/app/build.gradle

https://github.com/pestrada/android-tdd-playground/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Please follow these projects if the project working fine after you make build.gradle as it is shown in example then add multiple builds if then gives issues need to check also log.trace of android & maybe not supported.

make it simple then complex the solution so that you could find where is the error.

Comment: Hi Bav, it does work with 1 build type, but my project has multiple build types.